# sending email via php mail function

Tags: php, email

i have created a page for sending mail and i am using mail function of php. but when i run the script i am unable to send the mail.

i have a send mail link at this page http://vijayatech.freevnn.com/index.php 
when i click on this link it gets redirected to http://vijayatech.freevnn.com/mail.php where i have my code to send mail.

my code for sending mail is as follows:
this code is in my mail.php:

```
$message="hello";

$subject="hi";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail('ethanhunt19892020@gmail.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
```

i have a free domain at freevnn.com
anyone please help me out and tell me what is the problem

thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the emails are self-destructing after 30 seconds in-transit?

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me. One thing you may want to add to the headers is From: name@email.com

```
<?php

$message="hello";

$subject="hi";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: John Smith <john@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
$mail = mail('john@mail.com',$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($mail == 1) echo "Mail was sent";
else echo "Mail was NOT sent";
```

Hope that is helpful. Also try checking your spam folder.

Comment: it shows up the "Mail was NOT sent" do i have a problem with server.

Comment: i have just uploaded my pages on the server do i have to do something with mail server my domain is on http://www.freevnn.com.

Comment: i dont have an email account on this server as it is a free domain and they dont provide email account for free users can that be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you satisfied the [very important requirement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php) of using the mail function in PHP?